# Why do we subtract horizontal and vertical component of a electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, physics, electrostatic, electric-field

I was solving a question of electrostatic which is: Find the electric field at a distance z above one end of a straight line segment of length L that carries a uniform line large lambda.
My question is (from what i have understood from vector addition) for any vector A having Ax(horizontal component) and Ay(vertical component) we will have: vectorA= Ax i + Ay j. Which i have followed [image]

Now i have three questions(i am not clear with some of the basics i think)
1.) in the given solution they have taken Ex as negative (E=Ez - Ex)
2.) shouldnt the vertical component be in the y direction i.e., Ey
3.)for solving these kind of integration we substitute tan theta for simplifying the process. But in the most of the solution that i have seen, they dont vary the limit of integration even after the substitution and got the correct answer even so. Which i dont get.
(P.S i have also tried solving the question with my following observations but didnt get the right answer)

Comment: for 2D y is vertical, for 3D , xy are horizontal

Comment: Oh ohk and do you have any idea about my other questions. Thanks.

Comment: From the drawing it is obvious that projection of field vector onto _z_ axis is positive, and onto _x_ axis is negative. Is this the answer?